# Отладка графики в Visual Studio 2022

Tags: отладка, графика, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, directx-11

У меня такая проблемка. Хочу отладить графику DirectX11 в Visual Studio 2022. Нажимаю: Отладка -> Графика -> Начать отладку графики. Итог - Visual Studio 2022 не предоставляет мне никакой отладочной информации(скрин с демонстрацией проблемы из Visual Studio 2022):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил для проверки запустить отладку графики в Visual Studio 2019 - там всё работает корректно - отладочная панель ожила(скрин с демонстрацией из Visual Studio 2019):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему я не получаю никакой отладочной информации в Visual Studio 2022, в чём может быть проблема? В документации ответа на свой вопрос я не нашел, а отладить в новой студии хочется :-)

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил: установил пакет <Разработка игр на C++> в Visual Studio Installer